# Precise statement for "orbit of algebraic group is open in its Zariski closure" and source of proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

My question is about the precise clarification (and source of proof) of the following statement I have heard of:

Let $H$ be an algebraic group action on a variety $X$. Let $x\in X$. Then $H.x$ is open in its Zariski closure.

I don't know what conditions I am supposed to impose on $H$ and $X$. But the scenarios I often work with is $H$ as a subgroup of $G$, acting on some $G/L$, where all groups here are algebraic over $\mathbb R$.

Can anyone tell me what the precise statement of this is and where to find a proof (please tell me the number of theorem you refer to in some book, thanks). I do not know schemes and stacks so please refrain from quotient theories that are too abstract for the above settings.

Comment: It is very early in Chapter 2 of T.A. Springer's book, Linear Algebraic Groups